# "No collision" is too performance-heavy

Tags: performance, collision-detection, sprite-kit

I'm planning to do scrollshooter, so I need to collide only player with big number of bullets. Bullets don't collide with themselves. And I'm disappointed to see how fps drops when two sprites, that should not collide, pass through. I've tested with this code snippet:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
     }
    return self;
}

-(void)processTouch:(UITouch*)touch
{
    if(!(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded || touch.phase == UITouchPhaseCancelled))
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
        sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:sprite.size]; //CGSizeMake(1, 1)
        sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
        sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 0;
        sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;

        sprite.name = @"yourNode";

        sprite.position = location;
        [self addChild:sprite];

        double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));

        __block MyScene *blockSelf = self;
        __block UITouch *blockTouch = touch;

        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [blockSelf processTouch:blockTouch];
        });
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        [self processTouch:touch];
    }
}
```

And results are:

[image: All nodes are in the same place]
[image]

So what should I do? I think I may encounter situations where many nodes will be in the same place (spawning point, for example). Should I not use physics bodies and just write collision detection myself?

Comment: You should include draw count info as well. High draw count causes low frame rates. You could possibly improve that using texture atlas, and setting ignoreSiblingOrder to YES on your SKView.

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir please, elaborate. What is draw count?

Comment: For start you can display it by setting this on your skview     skView.showsDrawCount = YES;
This video will give you a very good idea about what draw count is http://www.codeandweb.com/what-is-a-sprite-sheet-performance

Comment: do not make any performance tests in the simulator - it's not a device so you will not get any real-world-applicable, tangible, comparable performance results!

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir draw count is 1 no matter how much items I have. It is clear that problem in physicsbody, because I can have ~4k nodes without big fps drop without physics.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D tested on iPad minute ago, same (literally, 450+ vs 120) results.

Comment: I removed my previous comment because I misread your question.  Isn't a situation where you have over 100 overlapping bodies a bit contrived though, even with streams of bullets flying around and hundreds of bodies on the screen not many will actually overlap at the same time.  Did this end up being a problem and did you have any luck with finding a solution?